# Checking if a branch exists in Jenkins shell script

Tags: shell, jenkins

I am having a trouble checking if a branch exists in a Jenkins job.
My shell scripts is as follows:

```
   set +e
   BRANCH_EXISTS=$(git ls-remote --quiet | grep -w ${BRANCH_NAME})
   if [[ -z $"{BRANCH_EXISTS}" ]]
    then
        echo "Branch does not exist"
   else 
     echo "Branch exists"
   fi
```

Following is a log:

```
07:36:26 + BRANCH_EXISTS='4cbe2d1776db4dc263a1e7884e35da49a0a6f309  refs/heads/equalizer_fe_testing'
07:36:26 + [[ -z {BRANCH_EXISTS} ]]
07:36:26 + echo 'Branch exists'
07:36:26 Branch exists
...
07:36:27 + BRANCH_NAME=test/fe-testing_staging1
07:36:27 ++ grep -w test/fe-testing_staging1
07:36:27 ++ git ls-remote --quiet
07:36:28 + BRANCH_EXISTS=
07:36:28 + [[ -z {BRANCH_EXISTS} ]]
07:36:28 + echo 'Branch exists'
07:36:28 Branch exists
07:36:29 Finished: SUCCESS
```

As you can see, in one case I check for a branch that does not exist. But still the if condition  passes. I have tried with `if [[ -n $"{BRANCH_EXISTS}" ]]` as well but still gets the same result.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly using the test operator to check if string is empty. In most shells, variable interpolation happens with `${var}` and not `{var}` or `$"{var}"`

```sh
$ var=foo
$ [[ -z $var ]] && echo ok
$ [[ -z $var ]] || echo ok
ok
$ var=
$ [[ -z $var ]] && echo ok
ok
$ [[ -z var ]] && echo ok     # does not assert, because literal 'var' is not empty
```

When you are doing `[[ -z {var} ]]` you are not interpolating `var`, but comparing against a literal string `{var}` which is *never* empty.

Change your conditional to `[[ -z "${BRANCH_EXISTS}" ]]` to make it work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

As Inian already explained in his answer, `$"{BRANCH_EXISTS}"`, but `"${BRANCH_EXISTS}"` would be correct. However, there is more to it:

In your case, the double quotes are not necessary, because no word splitting occures here after parameter expansion (since you are inside a  `[[....]]`. Hence you can write simply `[[ -z $BRANCH_EXISTS ]]`.

However, if the branch does not exist, `grep` will return a non-zero exit code, and the program will be aborted (due to your `set -e`. Therefore, the `then` branch of your conditional won't ever be executed, even if you would fix the conditional.